# Codeigniter not receive value from ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, cordova

I really need some help. I'm developing mobile app using **phonegap/cordova** and webservice using **codeigniter**. This app have register function which mean app will send data trough **Ajax** to **codeigniter** controller then save it into database. Actually its working fine in localhost. But after I transfer all **codeigniter** file to live server, **ajax** return error. I already setup config,database,base_url in codeigniter. Someone know what's the problem?

here is ajax code

```
var base_url = "http://bizprohandler.com/token/";

var reg = {"name": name, "email": email, "country": country, "mobile_number": mobile_number, "bitcoin_id": bitcoin_id, "user_id": user_id, "password": password};
$.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : base_url+'index.php/webservices/register',
        data       : reg,
        dataType   : 'json',
        timeout    : 2000,
        success: function(e){
            if(e.status == 0){
                $.mobile.changePage("#login",{reverse:false,transition:"slide"});
                alert(e.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

and this is codeigniter controller

```
public function register()
{
    $json = "";
    $result_array = array();

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $data = json_decode($json, true); //decode into array.\

    $name             = $data['name'];
    $email        = $data['email'];
    $country          = $data['country'];
    $mobile_number   = $data['mobile_number'];
    $bitcoin_id       = $data['bitcoin_id'];
    $user_id          = $data['user_id'];
    $password         = md5($data['password']);

    $this->user_model->insert_user($name,$email,$country,$mobile_number,$bitcoin_id,$user_id,$password);
    $result_array['status'] = 0;
    $result_array['message'] = 'Successfully registered';
    $rep = json_encode($result_array);
    echo $rep;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: what does `alert(e)` in success giving??

Comment: in localhost, if I do JSON.stringify(e), it alert {"status": "0", "message": "Successfully registered"}. but in live server, ajax will alert error.

Comment: What error is coming??

Comment: I alert('error'). So its mean ajax not success when trying to communicate with live server.

Comment: what i asked is, in console check for error. Some error is there in console, so ajax is entering to `error`

Comment: read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @SyazwiZaili in your ajax, try
`error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert(jqXHR); alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown);
                    }` to see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer as to why it is failing, but it will help you see what error is being returned. My proposed code for `register()` is more CodeIgniter-ish.

```
function register()
{
  // returns array of all POST items passed through the XSS filter
  $data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); 

  $this->user_model->insert_user($data);//you might need to modify insert_user()?
  $result_array['status'] = 0;
  $result_array['message'] = 'Successfully registered';
  echo json_encode($result_array);
}
```

As the code comment states, you might need to modify `user_model->insert_user()`. Since you didn't share that code it is unknown what is happening there. Unless you have special requirements for the insert, an straight-forward insert can be done with this: `$this->db->insert('yourTable', $data);`

The following AJAX code is modified so that `error: function...` will alert useful troubleshooting information.

```
var base_url = "http://bizprohandler.com/token/";
var reg = {"name": name, "email": email, "country": country, "mobile_number": mobile_number, "bitcoin_id": bitcoin_id, "user_id": user_id, "password": password};

$.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : base_url+'index.php/webservices/register',
        data       : reg,
        dataType   : 'json',
        timeout    : 2000,
        success: function(e){
            if(e.status == 0){
                $.mobile.changePage("#login",{reverse:false,transition:"slide"});
                alert(e.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```